# Android - Leave A Time Between ImageButton Animations?

Tags: android, android-animation, time-wait

I have 6 ImageButton. I applied the same animation to all of them as below:

```
Animation anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.wave_scale);
img1.startAnimation(anim1);
img2.startAnimation(anim1);
img3.startAnimation(anim1);
img4.startAnimation(anim1);
img5.startAnimation(anim1);
img6.startAnimation(anim1);
```

Now, I want to hav a free small time between one animation and the other (let's say 200 ms), so that they will not start at the same time. I tried to add `this.wait(200)` between each of the `startAnimation methods` but this didn't work.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary solution that I found until now is:

1. You need to re-define the same animation for each ImageView. Strange !
2. Before you assign it to an ImageView, you will setStartOffset() for your animation by whatever you want.

Wired But works fine !

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try this: `img1.setStartOffset(700);`
This will create a delay of 700 millsec before animation starts

Comment: Did you read the question? This is NOT what I want!  I said in the question: `I want to have a free small time between one animation and the other`.

Comment: BTW, setStartOffset is for animation, not Views !